# Node - How to test anonymous callback of stubbed dependency

Tags: node.js, jasmine, raspberry-pi, stubbing

I'm writing a nodejs module to abstract the detail of driving motors connected to Raspberry Pi's gpio headers.
The node module I'm using for communicating with the pi's gpio is [pi-gpio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pi-gpio)

I'm testing my module with `jasmine`, and because I know the `pi-gpio` module that I `require` has specific hardware requirements and that it won't run on my development PC (because it's not a pi), I am using [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to stub the dependency.

Consider the following (simplified) module:
**nodepibot.js**

```
'use strict';

var gpio = require("pi-gpio");

const LOW = 0,
    HIGH = 1;

const MOTOR_LEFT_ENABLE = 22,
    MOTOR_LEFT_A = 16,
    MOTOR_LEFT_B = 18;

var leftMotorStop = function leftMotorStop() {
    gpio.write(MOTOR_LEFT_ENABLE, LOW, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
};

module.exports = {
    "leftMotorStop": leftMotorStop
};
```

And my `jasmine` spec:
**nodepibotSpec.js**

```
describe("Node Pibot tests", function() {

    var nodepibot,
        stubGpio = {
            write: function() {}
        };

    beforeEach(function() {
        var proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();
        nodepibot = proxyquire("../main/nodepibot", {'pi-gpio': stubGpio});
    });

    it("Should stop left motor", function() {
        // Given
        spyOn(stubGpio, "write");

        // When
        nodepibot.leftMotorStop();

        // Then
        expect(stubGpio.write.callCount).toBe(1);
        expect(stubGpio.write).toHaveBeenCalledWith(22, 0, jasmine.any(Function));
    });

});
```

The above tests my 'happy path' - IE. I am asserting that when `leftMotorStop` is called on my module, then the `write` method is called on the `pi-gpio` library with appropriate parameters.

What I would like to be able to do is test the `un-happy path` - IE. to test the anonymous callback function when `err` has a value in which case I assert an exception is thrown back.

Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite your stubbed write function, to call the error function:

```
var nodepibot,
    stubGpio = {
        write: function(var1, var2, callback) {
            callback("stubbed error");
        }
    };
```